# WPF behaviors and events - attaching to proper events

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, triggers

I have here a behavior handling drag & drop, and I attach the mouse events through the view. The item's viewmodel inherit from `IDraggable`. I use Caliburn.Micro as MVVM framework.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <!-- item contents -->

                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior DraggableItem="{Binding}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="StartDrag" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="StopDrag" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseMove">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="Dragging" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then the behavior attaches the mouse events to the element's mouse handlers :

```
public class DragOnCanvasBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DraggableItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DraggableItem",
            typeof(IDraggable),
            typeof(DragOnCanvasBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((d, e) =>
            {
                ((DragOnCanvasBehavior)d).draggable = (IDraggable)e.NewValue;
            })));

    private IDraggable draggable;

    public DragOnCanvasBehavior()
    {
        this.StartDrag = new RelayCommand((o) =>
        {
            ((UIElement)this.AssociatedObject).MouseLeftButtonDown += this.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        });

        this.StopDrag = new RelayCommand((o) =>
        {
            ((UIElement)this.AssociatedObject).MouseLeftButtonUp += this.ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        });

        this.Dragging = new RelayCommand((o) =>
        {
            ((UIElement)this.AssociatedObject).MouseMove += this.ElementOnMouseMove;
        });
    }

    public IDraggable DraggableItem
    {
        get { return (IDraggable)this.GetValue(DraggableItemProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DraggableItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Dragging { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StartDrag { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StopDrag { get; private set; }

    // these handle the drag through the IDraggable properties
    // and the mouse event args
    private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {}
    private void ElementOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {}
    private void ElementOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}
}
```

It works, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here. The mouse events are attached in the behavior constructor, but they are "hard-linked" to the events (meaning I can't change the triggers to something else than mousedown/up/move).

I must, however, have access to the mouse position in the `ElementOnMousexxx` methods, so I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so it turns out that you don't *need* the `MouseEventArgs` to get the mouse cursor position, you can just use `System.Windows.Input.Mouse`. You also don't need the "sender" object, when using `Behavior<T>` you can just use `this.AssociatedObject`

```
public DragOnCanvasBehavior()
{
    this.StartDrag = new RelayCommand((o) =>
    {
        this.OnStartDrag();
    });
}

private void OnStartDrag()
{
    // get mouse position
    this.mouseStartPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);

    // access control properties
    ((UIElement)this.AssociatedObject).CaptureMouse();
}
```